# React onChange being used after a click of a button to alter value in input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

So I'm attempting to use my handleChange method within my React class when using a bootstrap datepicker.

```
<div className="col-xs-4">
  <div className="input-group date_calendar">
    <input className="form-control date_calendar" placeholder="Select a due date..." type="date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'" ref="scheduled_datetime" defaultValue={this.state.scheduled_datetime} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    <span className="input-group-btn">
      <label className="btn btn-link">
        <i className="fa fa-calendar text-muted"></i>
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want it to do is use the Bootstrap Datepicker and whenever I click a date, it fills out the `input` ref and then it calls my handleChange method.

But it seems, that onChange is not what I want. onChange only is used when I'm typing the value inside the input field, and not when the input field itself just changes.

Is there any way to basically call the handleChange method whenever that input field is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `handleChange` function within a callback event provided by the [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html). Use your ref in `componentDidMount` to both initialize and respond to these events.

```
componentDidMount() {
  $(this.refs.scheduled_datetime).datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', (e) => {
    //  e here contains the extra attributes 
    this.handleChange(e);
  });
}

// render() {...}
```

Comment: Quick sidebar question, is AJAX used in most React apps? While learning it I was told to stay away but if most people use it, then I'll use it more in my apps. Thanks!

Comment: react's life-cycle methods make handling ajax and other asynchronous calls easy, so yes it is used in most apps.

Comment: Quick update to this: It does work, but it seems that when you call `this.handleChange(e)`, it says handleChange is not a function, and that's because it is using the `this` of the jQuery inside the method and not the `this` of the React component. So unsure how you deal with that?

Comment: i'll assume your using babel, and as such you should use arrow functions, as they capture the `this` value of the enclosing context - see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Just want to say thanks for this. Solved a big headache for me.